# Get Words After Last Dot in Regex and JS

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I get the word after the last dot using Regex and JS?

```js
const yeah = 'SampleLibrary/21.0/Best.colour'

const hello = yeah.replace('(?<=\.|^)[^.]+$')

console.log(hello)
```

**EXPCTECTED OUTPUT**

`colour`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```js
const yeah = 'SampleLibrary/21.0/Best.colour'
const hello = yeah.replace(/^.+\./, '');
console.log(hello)
```

Comment: If I try `SampleLibrary/21.0/Bestcolour`. It outputs an error. It should get the `0/Best.colour` I think?

Comment: @Joseph Sorry, I thought by "word" you meant only alphabetic letters. I can update my answer.

Comment: There's still an issue. Its getting the words after the first `dot`. It should only get the words after the last `dot`

Comment: @Joseph I understand the problem now. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Joseph My answer now replaces the longest non-match instead of getting the largest possible match. This fixes the greediness problem and has worked in all the tests I've done.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks Michael!